# "Оптиковолоконный" или "оптико-волоконный" кабель?

Tags: орфография

Правильно ли говорить "оптиковолоконный" и если да, то в каких случаях, слитно, раздельно или через тире?

Answer (score 1):

" на чём основана Волоконно-оптическая связь?"

Это не на этом форуме обсуждать. Но вообще-то на эффекте полного внутреннего отражения электромагнитных волн на границе раздела диэлектриков с различными показателями преломления.

Словари фиксируют два равноправных и равнозначных варианта написания: **оптоволоконный** и **оптико-волоконный**

Comment: нет, технический аспект я знаю, а как правильно сказать не знал.
Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 0):

Есть устоявшееся словосочетание "оптическое волокно", следовательно, сложное прилагательное от него - со слитным написанием: "оптиковолоконный"; по аналогии с общепринятым словосочетанием "горные лыжи", образующим сложное прилагательное "горнолыжный", например в словосочетании "горнолыжный спорт". То есть, устойчивые общепринятые словосочетания образуют сложные прилагательные без дефиса (чёрточки), но есть ряд исключений, о которых можно прочесть на вполне хороших сайтах русской грамматики, да и просто в советских учебниках по русскому языку (подчёркиваю, в советских). Товарищи, и не путайте тире с дефисом. Тире в два раза длиннее и разделяет сложное предложение на меньшие ("Родину любить - родине служить", "Знание - сила" (это - два предложения, несмотря на то, что в каждом лишь одно слово)) и пространственно-временнЫе пределы (маршрут Москва - Минск, 1941 - 1945 гг.). К сожалению, создатели клавиатуры компьютера так её спроектировали, что почти всегда не добиться постановки настоящего тире - оно, как всегда выходит дефисом, а именно, коротким - вот и у меня здесь настоящее тире нигде не получилось, но хоть отступом от слов с обеих сторон выделяю. Дефис же применяется в сложных словах, например: "художник-декоратор", "лётчик-испытатель" (уточняет особенность главного понятия; но есть одно исключение и тут) и в некоторых категориях сложных прилагательных.Во общем, смотрим грамматические сайты - чем они больше, тем полнее освещают.

Comment: А кто путает-то? Тире отличается от дефиса не длиной (это чисто типографский трюк, в других случаях обычно игнорируемый) , а тем, что вокруг тире всегда есть пробелы (формулы и прочие цифровые случае выносим за скобки). Но если вам так хочется, набирайте тире из дух дефисов или пользуйтесь  Alt-вводом. Alt + 0151 - короткое (среднее), Alt + 0150 - длинное.

Comment: И да, подобные аналогии обычно опасны. Хотя тут особых споров и нет. Слитно пишется **по правилу**, а не **по аналогии**.